# grep file names from a text file and print the name of shell file calling that file into a text

Tags: shell, sed, grep, tee

I have some script name along with their path stored in a text file.
The text files contains paths like

```
 /myhome/new1/myfiles/test2.sh
 /myhome/new3/myfiles/test1.sh
 /myhome/new2/myfiles/test4.sh
 /myhome/new/myfiles/test5.sh
```

these shell files are being called by some main scripts

- I want to go the path, the main path are present in the path(i dont
  know how to get the path, couldn't sed last delimiter)
- I want to grep the filename(to get the file name use `sed 's/.*\///' 
  new.txt`) and store the **filename that is of type shell** script into a 
  text file.

The output in the **text file** should be something like 
path along with scriptname along with main script name

```
 /myhome/new1/myfiles/test2.sh  test2    test2main.sh
 /myhome/new3/myfiles/test1.sh  test1    test1foo.sh
 /myhome/new2/myfiles/test4.sh  test4    test4bar.sh
 /myhome/new/myfiles/test5.sh   test5    baz5main.sh
```

`test2main.sh`, `test1foo.sh`, `testo4bar.sh` ... are main scripts that call these files.

Comment: Help me understand that. You expect the command to read the file with those script paths. When it reads `/myhome/new1/myfiles/test2.sh`, it looks for script files in `/myhome/new1/myfiles/` which call `test2.sh`, finds `test2main` and prints a line with the path, file name with stripped `.sh` and the script that has been found?

Comment: command will look for the script in the script path `/myhome/new1/myfiles/` then search for the main scripts `test2main` or routines that are calling the script `test2.sh`....there may be other type of files that will call the script but only script file should be included in o/p.  to find the main script(that is present in the same directory as the script) I grep the script name `test2.sh` in the path and bunch of files pop out ......but i only need the shellscript.

Comment: @Philippos yes i think you have got it.

Comment: Okay, but what is the criterion to know it is a shellscript? A certain shebang line? Being executable? Having `.sh` ending?

Comment: having `.sh` extension is fine.

Comment: Then my updated answer should do the job if you have GNU `sed` (and I didn't make a mistake). Please comment the answer if it causes a problem or you have questions about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script to achieve this. From your question, it is not clear how exactly you determine the "main" file for each input file. In the script below, it is simply assumed to be the only other file in the folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r f  # every line is represented by $f
do
    d=$(dirname "$f") # $f's directory
    b=$(basename "$f") # $f's basename
    bwoe=${b%.*} # $f's basename without extension
    m=$(find "$d" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -name "$b" | head -n 1) # get first file in the folder that is not $f
    m=$(basename "$m") # basename of main file
    printf "%s\\t%s\\t%s\\n" "$f" "$bwoe" "$m"
done < input.txt # input.txt contains the input scripts
```

Example:

```
$ ls a b c
a:
afoo.sh  a.sh

b:
bmain.sh  b.sh

c:
c.sh  cxx.sh
$ cat input.txt 
a/a.sh
b/b.sh
c/c.sh
$ bash script.sh 
a/a.sh  a       afoo.sh
b/b.sh  b       bmain.sh
c/c.sh  c       cxx.sh
```

Comment: actually the folder contains subscripts and only 1 main script for all subscript, so i needed to check for only the 1 main script calling the scripts given to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly (see comment), GNU `sed`'s `e` flag to the `s` command can help you make it a one-liner (untested, sorry):

```
sed -E 'h;s_(.*/)(.*)_grep -l \2 \1*.sh_e;x;G;s_([^/]*).sh\n_\1.sh \1 _' scriptfile
```

- `h` saves the line in the hold space, so we can recover it laater after messing it up
- `s_.*/_grep -l \2 \1*.sh_e` is the actual trick: `.*/` matches everything upto the last slash, so `\1` will be the path, while `\2` will be the rest of the line (the script name). Now `grep -l` is inserted before the script name and before the path; thus `/my/path/foo.sh` becomes `grep -l foo.sh /my/path/*.sh`. The `e` flag executes this pattern in a shell, so it gets replaced by the list of `*.sh` files in `/my/path` that contain `foo.sh` (hopefully only one, otherwise the script needs to be adapted)
- The rest is easy: `x`change both buffers and append the hold buffer (now with the shell's answer) to the pattern
- `s_([^/]*).sh\n_\1.sh \1 _` does the cleanup, duplicate the script name (without the `.sh`) and remove the newline, so you should get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

The `c-shell` can be a real savior here:

```
% foreach line ( "`cat ./input.txt`" )
   printf '%s\t%s\t' ${line:q} ${line:r:t:q}
   printf '%smain\n' ${line:r:t:q}
end
```

Other methods are:

```
$ perl -F/ -pale '
   my($t) = $F[-1] =~ /([^.]+)/;
   $_ = join "\t", $_, $t, "${t}main" if /\S/;
' ./input.txt

$ sed -Ee '
   s|([^/.]+)\.[^/.]+$|&\t\1\t\1main|;t
   s|([^.]+)\.[^.]+$|&\t\1\t\1main|;t
   s|([^/]+)$|&\t\1\t\1main|
' ./input.txt
```

**Results:**

```
/myhome/new1/myfiles/test2.sh   test2   test2main
/myhome/new3/myfiles/test1.sh   test1   test1main
/myhome/new2/myfiles/test4.sh   test4   test4main
/myhome/new/myfiles/test5.sh    test5   test5main
```

**Notes:**

```
o We have to be verbose as we need to cover the various possible cases that may arise.
o GNU sed is needed.
```

Comment: According to the question, you can't rely on the script names to be `test1main` and so on, but it says to `grep` for the script name calling the other script. So your answer works for the example, but not for the real-world problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture groups in sed with extended regex (-r option) to grab the file name and replace the original string along with your scripts in the final output:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*\/)([^.]*)(.*$)/\1\2\3 \2 \2main/' test.txt 

(^.*\/) -- 1st Capture, the path 
([^.]*) -- 2nd Capture, the file up to the dot 
(.*$)   -- 3rd Capture, the file suffix
```

Comment: According to the question, you can't rely on the script names to be `test1main` and so on, but it says to `grep` for the script name calling the other script. So your answer works for the example, but not for the real-world problem.

Comment: According to the test data it looks like that's what he's looking for. The question was not stated very clearly, the example data should probably reflect the potential results for what he wants more clearly. It looks like you've updated it.